# multitouch not working as expected in leaflet on desktop

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have tested the map on an ipad and thought that it works so far, now i discover that there is a problem on the pc with multitouch systems

the problem seems to be that leaflet decides internally which events are taken. I couldn't defie touchstart as the event type.

when i watch this demo:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/
the following difference results on an iPad and a Windows 10 multi-touch screen. If I keep my finger on the screen, whether on the card or outside, I can still touch on the Ipad, but not on the desktop PC. the screen is blocked.

This must of course not be the case, because it is completely normal that the user of public information systems, e.g. puts one hand on the screen and touches with the other.

how can I fix this issue